# How to convert SQL query with sub query and count to JPA criteria builder

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to convert this SQL query to use a JPA criteria builder. 
The answer needs to be a double or a float.

```
SELECT CAST((COUNT(m.id) -
(SELECT COUNT(s.id) 
  FROM mobile_unit as s
  left JOIN incident as i ON s.incidentId=i.id
  JOIN organizational_unit as o ON s.organizationalUnitId=o.id
  WHERE (s.organizationalUnitId = 1 AND s.incidentId IS NULL))) AS float) 
/COUNT(m.id) 
FROM mobile_unit as m 
JOIN organizational_unit as o ON m.organizationalUnitId=o.id
WHERE m.organizationalUnitId = 1
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you want to use a subquery, when it's not correlated in any way to the outer query.  Wouldn't it make more sense just to do the query between the three tables once, and just do the calculations in the Java?  Also, joining to `incident` on an `incidentId` that you then filter out non-null values from seems completely redundant to me.  Lastly, you're not using either of the two joins to `organizational_unit`, so why bother with them?

Comment: @DavidWallace Thanks for the comment. The subquery return a count answer that I need to use in the outer query. I need the sub query to return only the count of mobile_unit that the incidentId is not null, maybe there is better way to do that.The join to original unit is only for the testing later in the project. In the end of the day I wrote 2 queries and did the calculation in the java code but still I would like to know if it is possible to do it in JPA.

Comment: Umm, I guess so.  I'm a bit vague on using JPA Criteria Builders for aggregate functions, which is why I hesitate to write out an answer.  But in the SQL, all you're effectively doing is counting the proportion of mobile_unit rows for which incidentId is not null, out of those where the organizationalUnitId is 1.  All the joins are irrelevant and can be completely removed.  So the shortest way I can find to write this in SQL is `SELECT CAST(COUNT(incidentId) AS FLOAT)/ COUNT(*) FROM mobile_unit WHERE organizationalUnitId = 1` - this is exactly equivalent to your SQL here.  The part that I ...

Comment: ... don't know how to help you with is putting the arithmetic into the Criteria Builder.

Comment: Is this question still outstanding? Is the issue that the query is returning an `INT` value rather than `DECIMAL` or `FLOAT`?

Answer (score 2):

Without testing this, here is a rough sketch of how this could be done.

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Float> cq = cb.createQuery(Float.class);

Root<MobileUnit> root = cq.from(MobileUnit.class);
// Join is actually unnecessary
root.join("organizationalUnit", JoinType.INNER);
cq.where(cb.equal(
    root.get("organizationalUnitId"),
    1
));

Subquery<Long> subquery = cq.subquery(Long.class);
Root<MobileUnit> subRoot = subquery.from(MobileUnit.class);
// Actually these joins are unnecessary, but you requested them..
subRoot.join("incident", JoinType.LEFT);
subRoot.join("organizationalUnit", JoinType.INNER);

subquery.select(cb.count(subRoot.get("id")));
subquery.where(cb.and(
    subRoot.get("organizationalUnitId").eq(cb.literal(1)),
    subRoot.get("incidentId").isNull()
));

cq.select(cb.quot(
    cb.diff(
        cb.count(root.get("id")),
        subquery
    ).as(Float.class),
    cb.count(root.get("id"))
));
```